# Как сделать запрос в запросе?

Tags: sql

Почему не работает такой запрос и как его изменить, чтобы все заработало ?

```
select * 
from table1 
where id = select table2_id 
    where name = 'something.zip';
```

Comment: взять подзапрос в скобки `(select table2_id 
    where name = 'something.zip')`

Comment: может понадобится вместо `id = ` применить `id in `

Comment: Если вам был дан правильный ответ, отметьте его галкой для тех, кто в дальнейшем наткнется на эту тему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых: у вас в подзапросе пропущен оператор FROM, следовательно неизвестно откуда выбираются данные

Во-вторых: SELECT выдает своим результатом таблицу, если там будет одно значение то ваш запрос сработает, но если их будет несколько, то будет ошибка. Поэтому, или так:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id = 
      (SELECT TOP 1 table2_id 
       FROM table2
       WHERE name = 'something.zip')
```

Либо так:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id in 
      (SELECT table2_id 
       FROM table2
       WHERE name = 'something.zip')
```

Либо объединить таблицы через JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table2_id 
WHERE table2.name = 'something.zip'
```

Второе и третье решение дадут одинаковые результаты, а вот первое, с равенством будет усекать строки оставляя только один (произвольный) id, поэтому равенство к результатам запроса лучше не применять.

Comment: Третье решение некорректное. Из-за `INNER JOIN` могут уйти ещё строки из `table1`, которые необходимо оставить. И поправьте `table_2` на `table2`.

Comment: @Denis, table1.table2_id было опечаткой, сейчас должно быть корректным

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае знак `=` можно использовать лишь когда есть 1 значение, а в вашем случае запрос в запросе вернёт целый столбец значений, равенство тут вызовет ошибку.

1. Запрос в запросе (подзапрос) должен быть у вас полноценным запросом, т.е. иметь `SELECT`, `FROM`. В данном случае лучше использовать `in`, так как подзапрос вернет столбец (массив) значений:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM table1 
   WHERE id IN (SELECT table2_id 
                FROM table2
                WHERE name = 'something.zip');
   ```
2. Для такого отсева строк с ненужным `id` можно также использовать соединение `INNER JOIN`. В основном работает быстрее, чем подзапросы, особенно на больших таблицах:

   ```
   SELECT t1.* 
   FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT table2_id 
                              FROM table2
                              WHERE name = 'something.zip') t2
        ON t1.id = t2.table2_id
   ```

   или

   ```
   SELECT t1.* 
   FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.id = t2.table2_id and t2.name = 'something.zip'
   ```