# Будут ли идентичны 2 запроса SQL?

Tags: sql

Отвечал сейчас на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563676/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5/563683) по SQL, увидел соседний ответ и задумался: а будут ли всегда идентичны по результату эти 2 запроса:

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table2_id 
WHERE table2.name = 'something.zip'
```

и

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT table2_id 
                           FROM table2
                           WHERE name = 'something.zip') t2
     ON t1.id = t2.table2_id
```

Могут ли быть случаи, когда эти 2 запроса на одной таблице выдадут разный ответ? Например, 1-й запрос выдаст меньше строк? Либо это полностью 2 идентичных запроса и при любых данных в таблицах `table1` и `table2` будут выдавать один и тот же результат?

Comment: Если в первый добавите `table1.*` вместо общей `*` выборки, то будут. А вот по времени выполнения одинаковыми они не будут.

Comment: после редакции по совету @AlexKrass, в чём ваши сомнения?

Comment: @AlexKrass поправил вопрос, чтобы было понятней, спасибо. Другое имел в виду

Comment: @3per поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это два разных запроса, но результат будет один и тот же.

В первом случае выполняется объединение и после этого множество выбранных элементов отсекается по параметрам: `A ⋂ B ⋂ C`. Во втором случае сначала выполняется отсекание элементов и только потом объединение: `A ⋂ (B ⋂ C)`. Где в данном случае `C ⊆ B`.

Согласно теории множеств это ассоциативная операция `(A ⋂ B) ⋂ C = A ⋂ (B ⋂ C)`

Другими словами тут вопрос лишь в том, что быстрее выполнится с точки зрения вычислительного процесса. А результат всегда будет одинаков.

Answer (score 0):

А еще можно сделать так

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.name = 'something.zip' 
    AND t1.id = t2.table2_id
```